# Unable to make FatJar for multiple external dependencies for Android Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying create a task in build.gradle in and Android project in Android Studio IDE. I've two external dependencies (networking library-volley and gson) that I want to bundle with my library. My fatJar task look like this:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
baseName = "myFatJar"

from ("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release/")
from {
    configurations.compile.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
}}
```

In "myFatJar", only "gson" got included, but not "android.volley". I don't understand whats wrong with above task OR if I'm missing something ?

[UPDATE]
I would have loved to use [Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to create fatJar, but it seems to be not supporting android-library or android-application.